# Is the json library a part of Python by default? Are the simplejson and json packages the same?

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x, simplejson

I am trying to use JSON with Django.

When I execute `import json` in the shell, I receive no errors. However, when I try to use `json_dumps()` or just `dumps()` I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'json_dumps' is not defined
```

Apparently my `json` import didn't work despite having no errors. How can I get it to work?

Additionally:

1. Are `simplejson` and `json` the same packages?
2. Which one is native to Python?
3. Which one is recommended under what scenarios?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your error doesn't have anything to do with your question. This is a simple matter of Python namespacing: the function is `json.dumps` not `json_dumps`.

However, `json` has been a part of the standard library since 2.5. `simplejson` is a separate library. Unless you know you need it, you should use `json`.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I got lot of online code that has json_dumps but none that mentioned it as json.dumps(). Can you also tel me this, If I have imported json, why dint calling dumps() work?

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe that for a second. **Every single** piece of documentation for the Python json library will talk about `dumps`, not `json_dumps` because that simply doesn't exist. And your second question shows a misunderstanding of how imports work in Python, which you can fix by going here: http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Comment: @preetam: `import json` makes the name `json` available in the code below it i.e., you can `json.dumps`, you can't `dumps`.

Comment: Oh ya. Sorry. I got confused between import and from * import *